# Laravel: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, database-schema

I am using schema builder to create a Mysql table. I am using Ubuntu 14.04.
My connection for Mysql in `config/database.php` is :

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'firstapp'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

And Code for creating table with schema builder on routes.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
Schema::create('art', function($newtable)
{
    $newtable->increments('id');
    $newtable->string('artists');
    $newtable->string('title',500);
    $newtable->text('discription');
    $newtable->date('created');
    $newtable->date('exhibition_date');
    $newtable->timestamps();
});
return view('welcome');
```

});

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i was using xampp mysql and this was also started `/etc/init.d/mysql` from terminal, Since i am using Ubuntu 14.04.

I solved the problem which i posted above then another problem came up Saying `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`.

I changed the .env file which is placed in the root directory of laravel and i changed the  Database Name name and password which i was using for mysql.
It solved that problem too and i am up and running.

Answer (score 0):

As far a as i know , you must create a migration file using

```
php artisan migrate:make yourtable
```

Then yo must go to database folder you will find a new migration file created , then you must open it , and fill it with your schema , once you finish , then run migration

```
php artisan migrate
```

And that's all you will see your new table created.

[Migrations laravel 5](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations)

Comment: @Shafee does the db data connection ok in your .env file?